# Why can't I join my Minecraft LAN server on Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft

I've been having some troubles with Minecraft. My family has a LAN server with a bunch of mods that lets us all play together, but my computer is not connecting to it. Whenever I try to get in, I get the following error message:

```
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out:
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Ubuntu version: 20.04

Minecraft version: 1.12.2 (The world uses this version)

Output of `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: inactive
```

Output of `sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68
```

Comment: @user68186 I have added in the requested information.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Multiplayer Minecraft feature to connect to a LAN server hosted on a different computer. I can access the internet, the problem is limited to Minecraft.

Comment: @user68186 I have added the output of `iptables -L` to the question. I'm not sure how to check the subnet in the LAN.

Comment: `io.netty.channel` is the Minecraft server response. You ARE reaching that server.

Comment: That's odd, it isn't launching the world, just giving me an error and letting me return to Servers.